# How to remove *| at start and |* at end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble creating a regex that matches `*|VALUE|*`

I want to remove `*|` and `|*` but the regex i use only detects `*|`

```
str = *|VALUE|*
str.replace(/(^\*\||\|\*$)/, '') // VALUE|*
```

The OR operator does not seem to trigger.

Comment: Use `\*\|[^|]+\|\*`.

Comment: `/^\*\|.*\|\*$/`

Comment: _"The OR operator does not seem to trigger."_ Why are you trying to use an or operator?

Comment: @JLRishe i want to replace both `*|` and `|*` from string so it has to match two things

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Ok, that doesn't really match your title, which is "how to match string that starts with `*|` and ends with `|*`, but I see what you were trying to do. I've trying to do there. I've incorporated that into my answer.

Comment: @JLRishe yup you are right changed my title

Comment: Why not use `substring` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Referring to this question's original title) `/^\*\|.*\|\*$/` matches a string that starts with `*|` and ends with `|*`.

So you can do this:

```js
var str = '*|VALUE|*';
var trimmed = str.replace(/^\*\|(.*)\|\*$/, '$1');

console.log(trimmed);
```

Or use your original regex, but with a `g` (global) at the end. And don't forget the second argument to `.replace`:

```js
var str = '*|VALUE|*';
var trimmed = str.replace(/(^\*\||\|\*$)/g, '');

console.log(trimmed);
```

Comment: @melpomene I thought I tried it. Checking...

Comment: So my regex was okay i just needed the `/g` it seems

Comment: @melpomene Somehow a stray \ got in there. It works now.

Comment: @NickA Not sure why I was escaping it. Must have been a typo or made a mistake when modifying OP's original regex.

Answer (score 3):

Your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/r7VMo5/1/) matches both cases. You don't need the capturing group `^\*\||\|\*$`.

You could use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var str = "*|VALUE|*";
str = str.replace(/^\*\||\|\*$/g, "");
console.log(str);
```

And indeed as @melpomene  mentioned in the comment, you should use `/g` flag that performs a global search.

Comment: The crucial bit is `/g`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you may want to capture each part of the regex separately and then use substitution inside of `str.replace`. [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). This can help you change a string such as `*|VALUE|*` to something like `(VALUE)` Firstly you should change the inside to `.*` which will simply match all characters between the two symbols you want.

```js
let str = `*|VALUE|*`
let result = str.replace(/^(\*\|)(.*)(\|\*)$/, "($2)")
console.log(result)
```